# Adding a small map after woocommerce thumbnails

Tags: php, css, wordpress, woocommerce

I would like to add a simple div with a small google maps after the thumbnails (lets say 150px height and 100% width of a parent) on my product page in woocommerce shop:

http://wp.petruss.pl/produkt/sportinghotelravelli/

I tried to look for woocommerce hooks, but unfortunately no hook for such thing.

Thanks for replies!

Answer (score 0):

Add following code to your theme's functions.php ---

```
add_action(‘woocommerce_before_single_product_summary’, ‘your_map_function’, 21);

function your_map_function(){
 echo 'Your map HTML here';

}
```

Comment: Hi Alice, according to this guide: https://businessbloomer.com/woocommerce-visual-hook-guide-single-product-page/ This is not a hook I'm looking for. I would like to place it after woocommerce_product_thumbnails hook

Comment: woocommerce_product_thumbnails is called in side woocommerce_product_images function, which calls woocommerce_product_thumbnails.... and this function's priority is 20, that's why I have added the function with priority 21 to call just after that.

Anyways, which ever hook you do use, if the problem is fixed then that's all ;) 

Still I am leaving this answer here as this may be handy for some other user too, as this is a very common question.